# Joomla slider and contact us page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i have made joomla template 2.5 but not finished so far.

1) I have a home page with slider i have made extra file for slider slider.php and include it in template.

now slider should be in only home page how it will be possible?

2) I have some other pages like about us, contact, product and categories.

how it will be possible with template to make a contact form and send it to client email id?

I have some more problems will describe but first want to sort out them and then proceed please help .

Comment: I'd suggest learning the fundamentals of Joomla

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Beginners

Comment: I am up one level read all before 4 month

Comment: I have just sorted out first and still have problem in second can you help me.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Do you have knowledge of joomla , actually i am working on local host so could not show you online. right now but may be tomorrow

Comment: In template i am only able to make home page what should i do to make page like contact us ect. in contact us page i have a form with fields like name, company name, email, msg ect. and i have to send them to client email, am able to do all of these by php but i have to do it in jTemplate how i would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a little confused as to what Joomla is. It's a content management system, thus runs on extensions. It's not like creating your own basic PHP based site and hard coding everything.

Don't hard code the slider into the template. Instead, create a module position where the slide is at the moment, then turn the slider into a module. Converting you widgets and so on when you already have the code is fairly simple.

As for the contact form, this is also an extension which is already built into Joomla. So, in the Joomla backend, on the top menu, go to:

Components/Contacts/Contacts

Create a new one and enter the necessary details.

Then, create a new menu item and set the "type" to "Single Contact". Or you could download a contact extensions from [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org). If you want to e-mail the members of the site, go to the Joomla backend, on the top menu go to:

Users/Mass Mail Users

Then simply go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

for your slider problem, if you want to display your slider only in landing page or front page then you have to check the front page in your index.php file and then start your slider so that your slider only work for front page like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    // Start display your slider
}
```

The about example will work in joomla2.5x version..

To know more check the [joomla DOC](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page)

And for your second question you have two options, one is create a component for contact and then apply on your template or try to find some already made contact components from joomla extensions. OR modify the current com_contect component.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply i am going to build them as you suggest if I find any problem will back to StackOverflow